# Is it possible to realize dynamical ForeignKey, or other way to achieve the requirement?

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to realize dynamical ForeignKey?

I have a Task class, which is used for Server model, IP model, WorkOrder model and so on.

```
class =Task(models.Model):
    """
    Task for Server, IP, WorkOrder ...
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=1024) 
    belong_to = models.ForeignKey(to=`There should be be `Server, IP, WorkOrder``)
    ....
```

My requirement is design one Task class, then relevance to one of the models, but in Django, looks like impossibility.

If this is not possible, is there other method to achieve it?

Otherwise I will write the Task for each model.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way around?  The foreign key should be in the `Server`, `IP`, and `WorkOrder` models, pointing to `Task`s.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Task` always relates to exactly one other asset - `Server`, `IP`, etc - and each other asset could have multiple `Task`s associated, I think [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) are the only built-in support for this. There are some down sides to using them, because now the framework has to resolve the relation type to determine what foreign record is referenced, but it might be easier than multiple `Task` classes.